# Adjust the margins of a book document class

Tags: margins, book-class, single-sided

I used to use this

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm,
   left=35mm, right=35mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm
}
\parskip=12pt
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}
\usepackage{appendix}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{ makecell}

%LONG TABLE FEATURES
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{} \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal} 
%%%%%%%%%%%% CAPTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\RequirePackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\NewTblrTheme{captionof}%   % <---
{\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
    }
 \DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption} "continue..."}
    }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%\geometry{margin=2cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\chaptername~\filleft\bfseries\fontsize{30}{00}\selectfont\thechapter}
  {14pt}
  {\vspace{-2em}\filleft\Large}
  [\vspace{0.5em}\titlerule]

\titleformat{\section}
  {\bfseries\large}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}[\vspace{-1.5em}]

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\bfseries\normalsize}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}[\vspace{-1.5em}]

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\bfseries\normalsize}
  {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[\vspace{-1.5em}]

\graphicspath{figure/}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.6}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}


\include{dedication}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\null\hfill {TABLE OF CONTENTS}} 
\usepackage{tocbibind}

%\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\ADDCONTENTSLINE}[3]{%
  \oldaddcontentsline{#1}{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\newcommand{\CAPinToC}{\let\addcontentsline\ADDCONTENTSLINE}
\newcommand{\noCAPinToC}{\let\addcontentsline\oldaddcontentsline}
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage %remove blank page

\usepackage{nomencl}%%%% LIST OF SYMBOLS
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{section one} the text starts from here. 
\section{section tow} the text starts from here.
\section{section three} the text starts from here.
\chapter{OVERVIEW}
\section{section one} the text starts from here. 
\section{section tow} the text starts from here.
\section{section three} the text starts from here.
\end{document}
```

to adjust the margins of my thesis, unfortunately, the margins I got are as shown

[image]

How can I adjust the margins of my document as shown in the code above? By the way, I tried to use this one too `\usepackage[hmargin=3.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}`

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Actually, it is not tedious but it is long code this is what can I share with you I edited the above code

Comment: I get 35 mm horizontal margins with your code. How do you measure the margins?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I downloaded it and when I try to print it the margins looked like as shown in the figure above

Comment: Where do you get the image you show? What kind of parameters are those? An PDF viewer normally does not know anything about the margins of the text on a page.

Comment: Maybe what you mean are the printer's settings which, however, have nothing to do with the margins of the text as set by (La)TeX.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I opened it through Adobe Acrobat and then viewed the page setup from the print window.

Comment: I have no idea what these margins mean but they are surely not the margins as set by the `geometry` package.

Comment: Well, I don't know how they would measure document margins at university. But I hope it doesn't matter. Thanks

Comment: Tell them to take a ruler and measure!

Comment: It seems strange to me to specify `a4paper` as an option to the document class, and then reset `paperwidth` and `paperheight` with `geometry`.

Comment: According to university instructions, I should add 'a4paper' and specify its size.

Comment: `\include{dedication}` never use `\include` in the preamble

Comment: `\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage %remove blank page`  the comment is wrong, this breaks latex, don't do that.

Comment: Note that the definitions of the top and bottom margins depend on the header and footer.  See Figure 2 (page 3) of the geometry manual.

Answer (score 0):

To long for the comment ...

I can't test your document example since it contain some errors, but, if I use your page layout settings, and add `showframe` package that I can see your page layout, I get expected correct result:

[image]

MWE which produce above image is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=35mm, vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

How do you measure showed borders data? Showed data apparently are wrong (if they are from Shoed page layout settings).

Try extend above MWE width some part of your document and at this use only necessary packages.

More help is possible to give when from your document example will be removed errors in code.

**Addendum:**
Regarding your comments and claims, that page borders are independent to settings in `geometry` package always the same ...

Please check the following MWE with a bit elementary/rude check about size of text block on A$ page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=35mm, vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xurl}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
From
\url{https://latexref.xyz/Units-of-length.html#:~:text=The%20(approximate)%20conversion%20to%20metric,035146cm.}
follows 

\medskip
1 Point, 1/72.27 inch. The (approximate) conversion to metric units is 1point = .35146mm = .035146cm.


\bigskip 
\textbf{width and height of text area on A4 page are:}

\medskip
\verb+\textwidth+ = \the\textwidth (points) is approx. 140mm (210mm - 2*35mm)

\verb+\textheight+ = \the\textheight (points) is approx. 247mm (297mm - 2*25mm)
\end{document}
```

Result is:

[image]

So, settings in `geometry` package works as is advertised. In the above document are left and right borders equal to 35mm, top and bottom are equal to 25mm.

Sorry, it is unclear, how you measure text border sizes and what is actually your problem. Your claims for my MWE doesn't holds.

What is going on in your document I can't say, since provided example is not compilable and hence can't be tested. On the first sight is not seems, that in it you change page layout, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: I will try yours and let you know

Comment: It's the same, there are no differences.

Comment: No, it is not. See image in my answer! left/right borders are 35mm wide,  and top/bottom 25mm. It is not clear how you measures their length.  Show us a proof for your claims!

Comment: When I downloaded my PDF file, I looked at the page setup properties. The borders as shown in the figure I posted in my question. Was what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you do this with my MWE too?

Comment: Yes, I got the same borders.

Comment: I doubt about your method, Just print the page generated by my MWE and than measure borders by rule.

Comment: I measured them by the rule, left/right borders are 3mm and top/bottom 2 mm. I really don't understand what is going on.

Comment: @b.als, see addendum to my answer.

Comment: I implemented the code as a new project (copy-paste it) to measure the borders and I got the same result.